# When is a cochain complex concentrated in a single degree?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category. Is there any useful criteria how to identify when a cochain complex is *quasi-isomorphic* to a complex concentrated in a single degree, that is the two are isomorphic in the derived category $D(\mathcal A)$? Such criteria could be about employing homological dimension or a certain class of cochain complexes of which such identification is tautological for the class. I don't mind criteria identifying when they are homotopic too.

My apology if similar question had been asked before as I couldn't find it to the best of my effort.

Comment: Are you aware that a complex $X$ is quasi-isomorphic to a complex concentrated in a single degree if and only if the cohomology of $X$ is concentrated in a single degree?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Hi. One direction is clear but I fail to see the converse. In particular I am not sure how to construct a canonical morphism $X^m\rightarrow H^m(X)$.

Comment: In general there is no canonical morphism that way. But you can pass through a nice truncation of $X$ and then project. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ has cohomology concentrated in a single degree. Without loss of generality let that degree be $0$. Consider the complex
$$\tau_0X:\cdots \to X_2\to X_1 \to Z_0X \to 0 $$

This complex is a subcomplex of $X$, and the inclusion $\tau_0X \to X$ is a quasi isomorphism.

Now consider the complex

$$H_0  :\cdots \to 0 \to 0 \to H_0(X) \to 0 $$

There is a projection $\tau_0X \to H_0 $, which is a quasi-isomorphism. In conclusion, $X$ is weakly equivalent to $H_0$.

---

*Add*. The complex $\tau_j X$ with $(\tau_j X)_i = X_i$ if $i>j$, $(\tau_j X)_j = Z_jX$ and $(\tau_j X)_i = 0$ if $j<i$ is called the (good) truncation of $X$. Note that it is a subcomplex of $X$ with the property that the inclusion $\iota_j : \tau_j X\longrightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism in homology degrees $i\geqslant j$.